# React-Redux list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I believe that I now understand the flow of react-redux.  However, there are some things that confuse me.

Right now I have a working reducer updating the state, with the action, "ADD_ITEM".  This is working fine.  But I want that data to persist. So I am also storing that item into my database. When the page is refreshed and the state it reset, I obtain a list from the server with all the items and dynamically dispatch the "ADD_ITEM" action. This is also working fine, but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

The real problem arises when I connect the state to props in my component. In componentwillmount() I call the populateItems() dispatcher which dynamically adds the items to the state. However, the props for the item list seem to be coming in one at a time, and so I can't really display all the item at once but have to constantly update keep updating the list as props are coming.

Sorry, I am very new to the both react and redux, but this issue is one that I absolutely need assistance on. If you need clarification or code snippets, I'll be glad to share.

EDIT: Here are some code snippets

```
  let itemID = 0;
export function populateList(id) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`/api/item/getItems?ID=${id}`).then((res) => {
            console.log("Response:", res);
            res.data.map((data) => {
                dispatch(addToItemList(data));
            })
        })
    }
}

export function addToItemList(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return {
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        id: itemID++,
        itemName: data.name,
        itemDescription: data.description
    }
}

export function addItem(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.post('/api/item/add', data).then(res => {
            dispatch(addToItemList(data));
        })
    }
}
```

The reducer just adds the pre-existing list.
If I were to change the action to bulk-add the entire list from the database, I would have to parse that list differently than if one item were added manually.

Comment: You can just use an action which sets all items at once

Comment: Put all of your relevant code here if you can, so that it is easier to help you.

Comment: Include code please

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  There are just a few adjustments on the concept.
The flow is actually.

A user dispatch an action from the component, then an action receives a payload / data from the component, the Action converses with the reducer which in this case is just a piece of a big tree of data.

Flow example:

```
Component dispatch action ( onClick(dispatch(DoAction)) )  => 

DoAction will listen  => 

const DoAction = (data) => {

  return { type: 'BEGIN_ACTION', data }
};


The reducer will receive this action => 

 export default (state = initialState, action) =>  {
  if (action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'BEGIN_ACTION':
        return {
          show: true
        }
      case 'FAIL_ACTION':
        return initialState
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
}
```

==================// ==========================================

The big deal here is something called `connect` by `react-redux`

It wraps the component, which make the magic happens:

- Connect the actions to reducers
- Inject the dispatch function into `props`
- Allow you retrieve some data from the store

This is a source of a lot of confusion.

Now coming to the question:

It's advised to only finalize your API calls or trips to database via actions once you have a reference that it was executed successfully. 
You can either choose between Actions or even in the very component.

Try to close the cycle of Requests with an Action on the **callback of a** **promise**

ex: to call database inside of an Action:

```
export const login = (credentials) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginBegin())
    return auth.login(credentials).then((user) => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(user));
      browserHistory.push('/home');

    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(loginFail(error.response));
    });
  };
};
```

I hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use middleware such as [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) to batch your actions, and notify subscribers only once.